# Why does the term "gondola" refer to BOTH a Venetian canal boat AND an enclosed lift up a mountain?

Tags: etymology, differences, terminology, historical-change, transatlantic-differences

The first time I encountered the word “gondola” was as a 20 year old on her first visit to Venice. Gondolas, to me, were written in my memory as a flat, fancy, romantic (and expensive to ride) boat structures that traverse the canals of Venice, Italy.

But soon thereafter, on my first visit to Banff, Canada (Canadian Rockies) -- Gondolas was also the term for ski-like lifts (enclosed from the elements) to get from the bottom to the top of steep mountains (vice versa).

#### What is the etymology of “gondola”?

**And how did it develop to reference two completely different transportation devices?**  One on water, the other on mountains? What is the relationship besides their obvious transportation connect?

Comment: Probably because "gondola" was "borrowed" from the boat, as a name for the baskets below early passenger-carrying hot-air balloons, and the early cable car baskets resembled balloon gondolas.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gondola

Comment: In this [1839 Dictionnaire technologique](https://books.google.fr/books?id=kOc2yGZnVN4C&pg=PA431&lpg=PA431&dq=gondole+Petite+nacelle+d%27a%C3%A9rostat.&source=bl&ots=57y72VrjId&sig=Q5ZC7DSd5UZwplnbtBK6jC9ei00&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-mKuTlP_RAhUiAZoKHff5B6wQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=gondole%20Petite%20nacelle%20d%27a%C3%A9rostat.&f=false), "gondole" is both defined as the well known Venitian boat and as the small basket suspended under a hot air balloon (what is quite similar to the ski lift cabin)

Comment: English is full of words with multiple definitions.

Comment: Another useful question about a word with an interesting sequence of meanings, reduced to second-class citizenship on this site through enforcement of a fundamentally irrelevant technicality.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some of the successive meanings given in the OED are:

- 1a. " A light flat-bottomed boat or skiff in use on the Venetian canals, having a cabin amidships and rising to a sharp point at either end; it is usually propelled by one man at the stern with a single oar."
- 3. *U.S.* A large flat-bottomed river boat of light build; a lighter; used also as a gun-boat.
- 4a. "= gondola-car n. U.S.", which is glossed as "*U.S.* a railway car having a platform body with low sides."
- 4b. "An elongated car attached to the under side of a dirigible balloon or airship.  [German, Dutch *gondel*.] Also *transf*., applied to a structure that resembles such a car in its purpose and mode of attachment."
- 4c. "The car attached to a ski-lift. Also *gondola lift*."

So the crucial step appears to be the cabin of an airship (which is long and low), and then a cabin suspended from something. This kind of [semantic drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) is very common.

Answer (score 4):

The Venetian gondola appears (in italics, signifying a recently foreign, not altogether naturalized word) in Samuel Johnson, *A Dictionary of the English Language* (1756):

> ***GONDOLA***. *s.* {*gondole*, French.} A boat much used in Venice ; a small boat.

The next definition to arrive appears in Noah Webster, *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1847) which lists it after a lengthy entry describing the Venetian *gondola*:

> **GONDOLA**, *n.* ... **2.** A flat-bottomed boat for carrying produce &c. *United States.*

Merriam-Webster's *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1864) adds a third definition:

> **GONDOLA**, n. ... **3.** A long platform car, either having no sides or with very low sides, used on railways.

Meriam-Webster's *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, third edition (1916) drops the platform car definition (although that meaning returns in subsequent editions of the Collegiate Dictionary series) and adds a new third definition:

> **gondola**, *n.* ... **3.** A elongated car attached to the underside of a dirigible balloon.

Then, *Webster's Seventh New Collegiate Dictionary* (1963) lists a profusion of new definitions:

> **gondola** *n* ... **[4] b :** an often spherical airtight enclosure suspended from a balloon for carrying passengers or instruments **5 :** an upholstered chair whose back curves forward at both sides to form the arms **6 :** a fixture approachable from all sides used in self-service retail stores to display merchandise **7 :** a motortruck or trailer having a large hopper-shaped container for transporting mixed concrete

In the *Seventh Collegiate* definition 4(a) is the "elongated car attached to the underside of an airship" meaning that had debuted with a very similar wording almost half a century earlier. But even the *Seventh Collegiate* doesn't mention the "ski-lift car" meaning of the term. That finally appears as new definition 4(c) in *Webster's New Collegiate* [eighth edition] (1973):

> **gondola** *n* ... **[4] c :** an enclosed car suspended from a cable and used for transporting passengers; *esp* : one used as a ski lift

So in Merriam-Webster's telling, the closest etymological ancestors of the ski-lift-enclosed-car *gondola* was the airtight-enclosure-suspended-from-a-balloon *gondola*, and before that the elongated-car-attached-to-the-underside-of-a-dirigible *gondola*. In all likelihood, the elongated car of the dirigible reminded people of the railway-platform-car *gondola*, which in turn resembled the U.S.-produce-carrying *gondola*, which owed its name to the original Venetian *gondola*.

Now if only we could figure out how the approachable-from-all-sides-merchandise-displaying-fixture *gondola* got its name, we could rest easy.